# How to compare file "with itself" in Jetbrains IDEs?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff, clion

I have file with differences marked up with

```
<<<<<<< filename.cpp
    some code
=======
    some another code
>>>>>>> filename.cpp
```

is it possible (and how) to open it in two parallel panes in Jetbrains IDEs?

Answer (score 0):

are these two different files,
could this help 
http://jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html

you can right-click on the file and there should be compared with and you chose the same file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ultimate Edition.

It looks like you are doing a Git merge on the file and have conflicts.
You should be able to right click on the file and I think under the Git menu choose Resolve. This will bring up a side by side reference to see the changes in a readable view where you can pick and choose what to keep.

Another option if you have version control setup properly in the editor there is a tab that you can open and select the file and right click to do a diff to what the differences are as well.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't really matters if you are using CE or ultimate edition. Both have the same ui for merging conflicts.